# In Python: How can I merge these two dataframes without running into Memory Error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that I want to combine with each other in a specific way (see below). Both dataframes are somewhat large and I had problems with Memory Error, as well as programs running for a very long time.

The first dataframe contains two IDs (ID_1 and ID_2) and a timestamp, as well as an event. There can be multiple ID_2 mapping to one ID_1. There can also be multiple ID_1 and ID_2 mapping to a timestamp. ID_1, ID_2 and the timestamp all have duplicates in their respective column. The original dataframe has a length of 8,732,787 rows.

```
event_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
            'ID_2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
            'Timestamp': ['1984-05-11 14:30:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 15:30:00', 
                          '1990-12-11 09:10:00', 
                          '1975-01-08 23:23:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 14:30:00'],
                'Event': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
               }
event_df = pd.DataFrame(event_df)
event_df['Timestamp'] = event_df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

The second dataframe contains the same IDs and also a timestamp. This timestamp is different from the one of the first dataframe. It indicates at what time a blood sample was taken. The analysed blood parameters are columns as well (in the original dataframe 22 parameters, in this case for example purposes only 3). There are some missing values in each sample. The original dataframe has a length of 328,340 rows.

```
lab_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
          'ID_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          'Timestamp_Lab': ['1984-05-11 14:00:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 14:15:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 15:00:00',
                            '1975-01-08 20:00:00',
                            '1984-05-11 14:00:00'],
          'Hemoglobin': [np.nan, 14, 13, 10, 11],
          'Leukocytes': [123, np.nan, 123, 50, 110],
          'Platelets': [50, 50, 50, 110, 50]
         }
lab_df = pd.DataFrame(lab_df)
lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'] = lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

My goal is to add the parameters of dataframe 2 to dataframe 1, if the timestamp of the blood sample (dataframe 2) is earlier than that of the timestamp from dataframe 1. If there are missing values in between multiple parameters of the same type they should move one position up. If a column is completely empty it is dropped. Empty rows can be filtered as well. It should look something like this:

```
result = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
          'ID_2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
          'Timestamp': ['1984-05-11 14:30:00', 
                        '1984-05-11 15:30:00', 
                        '1990-12-11 09:10:00', 
                        '1975-01-08 23:23:00', 
                        '1984-05-11 14:30:00'],
          'Event': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
          'Hemoglobin_1': [14, 14, np.nan, 10, 11],
          'Hemoglobin_2': [np.nan, 13, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Leukocytes_1': [123, 123, np.nan, 50, 110],
          'Leukocytes_2': [np.nan, 123, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Platelets_1': [50, 50, np.nan, 110, 50],
          'Platelets_2': [50, 50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Platelets_3': [np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]          
}
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Do you have any suggestions how I could add the parameters of dataframe 2 to dataframe 1, while at the same time using an approach that doesn't lead to a memory error?

I tried merging the two dataframes with an 'outer merge' and then afterwards used boolean indexing to filter the rows with the laboratory data that lie after the timestamp of the event_df. After that I pivoted the parameters of the dataframe wider so that each row corresponds to the rows of the event_df again. This works for smaller dataframes, but produces a memory error for the original dataframe. I then tried to read in the event_df chunkwise, merge it and afterwards wrote it chunkwise into a csv. This process took about 8 hours and produced a 130GB csv file. I also ran into trouble with this approach when pivoting the merged dataframe wider afterwards. I was wondering if there was a more elegant or efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main issue when using pandas for large datasets, the OOM (out of memory) errors are really common especially in a "Cross-Join" like scenario by applying the outer merge in your case.

The best thing would be to move away from Python + Pandas to a distributed computing framework like Databricks/Spark where you would leverage cluster parallel computing, memory management, delta lake optimizations, and columnar data format which would speed up your query certainly. However, if you can't use any of those, I'd suggest the following:

- **Try using datetime instead datetime64 or convert to a small-size data format:** By default, pandas doesn't allocate the most efficient data. Casting to a smaller type will free up more memory when merging data.
- **Process your data into mini-batches and checkpoint the results after merge** You can split your workloads by months to reduce your data universe, and checkpoint the intermediary results in order to free up the massive memory usage. Normally I say, for processing data "it's better a machine gun than a bazooka".
- **Apply ThreadPoolExecutor for parallel execution:** You can read your data per month and trigger the merge operation in parallel per week.
- **Reduce the logic into small steps**: Apparently, by doing the outer merge you are doing all the logic at once. You can try creating indexes in each data frame that maps each blood info (e.g. 1 hemoglobin, 2 platelets etc) then perform the outer merge only with the `ID_1, ID_2, DateTime and the indexes`,  apply the index filter as you did, checkpoint the results, and finally join back to pick up all the columns you need from dataframe 1 or dataframe 2 according to the index created in the beginning. This is an extra step but could leverage to a more lean workflow in the end.
- **Avoid CSV for checkpointing your intermediary data:** CSV is not column-wise compressed format, so try using parquet to perform all processing if possible.
- **Try using Polars for more efficient data processing:** Pola.rs makes pandas operations more efficient given it leverages the PyArrow https://www.pola.rs/

Other nice links:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-memory-management/
- https://medium.com/bigdatarepublic/advanced-pandas-optimize-speed-and-memory-a654b53be6c2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach using [python-polars](/questions/tagged/python-polars) as mentioned in another answer.

It's using [`.from_pandas()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_pandas.html#polars-from-pandas) to load the data from your existing pandas dataframes, however ideally you'd use the correct lazy loading method depending on where your data lives e.g. [`pl.scan_csv()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html#polars-scan-csv) for CSV files.

If CSV is not a requirement for the output, consider using parquet instead: [`out.sink_parquet()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet)

```
import polars as pl

df = (
   pl.from_pandas(event_df).lazy().with_row_count()
     .join(
        pl.from_pandas(lab_df).lazy(), 
        on = ['ID_1', 'ID_2'], 
        how = 'left',
     )
)

cols = ['Hemoglobin', 'Leukocytes', 'Platelets']

out = (
    df.with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col('Timestamp') > pl.col('Timestamp_Lab')).then(
            pl.col('Timestamp_Lab', *cols)
        )
    )
    .with_columns(
       pl.when(pl.when(pl.all() == None).then(True).forward_fill().over('row_nr')) # shift everything after first null
         .then(pl.all().shift(-1).over('row_nr'))
         .otherwise(pl.all())
    )
    .groupby('row_nr', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
       pl.col('ID_1', 'ID_2', 'Timestamp', 'Event').first(),
       *cols
    )
    .with_columns(
       pl.col(col).list.to_struct(
          n_field_strategy = 'max_width',
          fields = lambda idx, col=col: f'{col}_{idx + 1}', 
       ) 
       for col in cols
    )
    .unnest(*cols)
    .drop('row_nr')
)

# out.sink_parquet('output.parquet')
print(out.collect())
```

```
shape: (5, 13)
┌──────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ ID_1 ┆ ID_2 ┆ Timestamp           ┆ Event ┆ Hemoglobin_1 ┆ Hemoglobin_2 ┆ Hemoglobin_3 ┆ Leukocytes_1 ┆ Leukocytes_2 ┆ Leukocytes_3 ┆ Platelets_1 ┆ Platelets_2 ┆ Platelets_3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64   ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ i64         ┆ i64         ┆ i64         │
╞══════╪══════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1984-05-11 14:30:00 ┆ 0     ┆ 14.0         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 123.0        ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 50          ┆ 50          ┆ null        │
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1984-05-11 15:30:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 14.0         ┆ 13.0         ┆ null         ┆ 123.0        ┆ 123.0        ┆ null         ┆ 50          ┆ 50          ┆ 50          │
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 1990-12-11 09:10:00 ┆ 0     ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        │
│ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 1975-01-08 23:23:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 10.0         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 50.0         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 110         ┆ null        ┆ null        │
│ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 1984-05-11 14:30:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 11.0         ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 110.0        ┆ null         ┆ null         ┆ 50          ┆ null        ┆ null        │
└──────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, since I don't know the polars functions all to well yet. Unfortunatley when I use out.sink_parquet('output.parquet') I get the following error 'PanicException: sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()''. When I use the out.collcet().write_parquet() function I get 'memory allocation of 2235592704 bytes failed' and 'Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)'. Do you know if this is fixable?

Comment: @kobue1 My bad, I didn't test the sink_parquet call - there must be a specific part of the query not yet supported for sinking - i'll try debug it. You can try add `streaming=True`, `out.collect(streaming=True).write_parquet()`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join), then reshaping:

```
import janitor

cols = ['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'Timestamp', 'Event']
vals = ['Hemoglobin', 'Leukocytes', 'Platelets']

out = (event_df.reset_index()
       .conditional_join(lab_df,
                         ('ID_1', 'ID_1', '=='),
                         ('ID_2', 'ID_2', '=='),
                         ('Timestamp', 'Timestamp_Lab', '>=')
                        )
       # remove unneeded level and duplicated columns
       .droplevel(0, axis=1).loc[:,lambda d: ~d.columns.duplicated()]
       # reshape to long form to push the non-NA at the beginning
       .melt(['index']+cols, value_vars=vals).dropna(subset=['value'])
       .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['index', 'variable']).cumcount().add(1))
       # reshape to wide form and flatten the MultiIndex
       .pivot(index=['index']+cols, columns=['variable', 'n'], values='value')
       .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1))
       .reset_index(cols)
       # restore rows without a match
       .pipe(lambda d: d.combine_first(event_df)[list(d)])
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID_1  ID_2           Timestamp  Event  Hemoglobin_1  Hemoglobin_2  Leukocytes_1  Leukocytes_2  Platelets_1  Platelets_2  Platelets_3
0     1     1 1984-05-11 14:30:00      0          14.0           NaN         123.0           NaN         50.0         50.0          NaN
1     1     1 1984-05-11 15:30:00      1          14.0          13.0         123.0         123.0         50.0         50.0         50.0
2     1     2 1990-12-11 09:10:00      0           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
3     2     1 1975-01-08 23:23:00      1          10.0           NaN          50.0           NaN        110.0          NaN          NaN
4     3     1 1984-05-11 14:30:00      1          11.0           NaN         110.0           NaN         50.0          NaN          NaN
```