# Is pivoting wider in DuckDB on an index column possible?

Tags: python, sql, pivot, duckdb, oom

I'm currently  working on a dataframe that I want to create out of two different dataframes with the difficulty that I'm constantly running into memory error. I have already posted a question about it here:
[In Python: How can I merge these two dataframes without running into Memory Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481153/in-python-how-can-i-merge-these-two-dataframes-without-running-into-memory-erro/76502879?noredirect=1#comment134916672_76502879)
This is how the two dataframes look  like:

```
event_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
            'ID_2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
            'Timestamp': ['1984-05-11 14:30:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 15:30:00', 
                          '1990-12-11 09:10:00', 
                          '1975-01-08 23:23:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 14:30:00'],
                'Event': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
               }
event_df = pd.DataFrame(event_df)
event_df['Timestamp'] = event_df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]')

lab_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
          'ID_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          'Timestamp_Lab': ['1984-05-11 14:00:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 14:15:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 15:00:00',
                            '1975-01-08 20:00:00',
                            '1984-05-11 14:00:00'],
          'Hemoglobin': [np.nan, 14, 13, 10, 11],
          'Leukocytes': [123, np.nan, 123, 50, 110],
          'Platelets': [50, 50, 50, 110, 50]
         }
lab_df = pd.DataFrame(lab_df)
lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'] = lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

This  is how I want the end result to look like:

```
result = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
          'ID_2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
          'Timestamp': ['1984-05-11 14:30:00', 
                        '1984-05-11 15:30:00', 
                        '1990-12-11 09:10:00', 
                        '1975-01-08 23:23:00', 
                        '1984-05-11 14:30:00'],
          'Event': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
          'Hemoglobin_1': [14, 14, np.nan, 10, 11],
          'Hemoglobin_2': [np.nan, 13, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Leukocytes_1': [123, 123, np.nan, 50, 110],
          'Leukocytes_2': [np.nan, 123, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Platelets_1': [50, 50, np.nan, 110, 50],
          'Platelets_2': [50, 50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
          'Platelets_3': [np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]          
}
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Although comments from  the last post have been helpful, the memory issue has not been solved. I therefore tried to use DuckDB in Python.

With Python code I originally tried to join the two dataframes on ID_2 and then remove some rows under the condition that the Timestamp_Lab is "larger" than  the Timestamp from event_df. In SQL this can be done in one go, which is quite nice. Afterwards I grouped the Timestamps and SMID in Python and then indexed them. I did that so that I could pivot it wider afterwards using the newly created index, like this:

```
parameter = merged_df.columns[5:] #select all parameter names
merged_df['Index'] = merged_df.groupby(['Timestamp', 'ID_2']).cumcount() + 1
join = merged_df.pivot_table(index='Timestamp', columns='Index', values = parameter)
event_df = event_df[event_df.columns[0:5]]
event_df = event_df.merge(right=join, how='left',on= ['Timestamp', 'ID_2'])
```

In SQL I added the index like this:

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_df.ID_2, Timestamp ORDER BY Timestamp_Lab) AS GroupIndex
FROM event_df
    LEFT JOIN lab_df
        ON event_df.ID_2 = lab_df.ID_2 AND event_df.Timestamp >= lab_df.Timestamp_Lab
```

But now I'm having trouble pivoting. I tried the following, but I gives me  a  ParserError (I'm  not  very familiar with  the syntax):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_df.ID_2, Timestamp ORDER BY Timestamp_Lab) AS GroupIndex
    FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM event_df
               LEFT JOIN lab_df
                  ON event_df.ID_2 = lab_df.ID_2 AND event_df.Timestamp >= lab_df.Timestamp_Lab
    ) subquery
)
PIVOT (
    ON GroupIndex
    USING (Hemoglobin)
    GROUP BY even_df.ID_2, Timestamp
) AS pivoted_data
```

My question therefore is:
Is a pivot on the index (as I did in Python) possible in SQL and if it is, how would it look like? I tried it, but couldn't  get  it to work. Even focusing on one parameter (e.g. Hemoglobin) and leaving out  the rest would already  help  me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

event_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
            'ID_2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
            'Timestamp': ['1984-05-11 14:30:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 15:30:00', 
                          '1990-12-11 09:10:00', 
                          '1975-01-08 23:23:00', 
                          '1984-05-11 14:30:00'],
                'Event': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
               }
event_df = pd.DataFrame(event_df)
event_df['Timestamp'] = event_df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]')

lab_df = {'ID_1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
          'ID_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          'Timestamp_Lab': ['1984-05-11 14:00:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 14:15:00', 
                            '1984-05-11 15:00:00',
                            '1975-01-08 20:00:00',
                            '1984-05-11 14:00:00'],
          'Hemoglobin': [np.nan, 14, 13, 10, 11],
          'Leukocytes': [123, np.nan, 123, 50, 110],
          'Platelets': [50, 50, 50, 110, 50]
        }
lab_df = pd.DataFrame(lab_df)
lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'] = lab_df['Timestamp_Lab'].astype('datetime64[s]')

print(lab_df.pivot_table(index=lab_df.index, columns=['ID_1'], values=['Hemoglobin', 'Leukocytes', 'Platelets']).join(lab_df).drop(['Hemoglobin', 'Leukocytes', 'Platelets'], axis=1))
```

I am joining the pivoted table again, to get the columns which were dropped during and later on dropping the columns, which we pivoted.

```
   (Hemoglobin, 1)  (Hemoglobin, 2)  (Hemoglobin, 3)  (Leukocytes, 1)  (Leukocytes, 2)  (Leukocytes, 3)  (Platelets, 1)  (Platelets, 2)  (Platelets, 3)  ID_1  ID_2       Timestamp_Lab
0              NaN              NaN              NaN            123.0              NaN              NaN            50.0             NaN             NaN     1     1 1984-05-11 14:00:00
1             14.0              NaN              NaN              NaN              NaN              NaN            50.0             NaN             NaN     1     1 1984-05-11 14:15:00
2             13.0              NaN              NaN            123.0              NaN              NaN            50.0             NaN             NaN     1     1 1984-05-11 15:00:00
3              NaN             10.0              NaN              NaN             50.0              NaN             NaN           110.0             NaN     2     1 1975-01-08 20:00:00
4              NaN              NaN             11.0              NaN              NaN            110.0             NaN             NaN            50.0     3     1 1984-05-11 14:00:00
```